# aws powershell Get-EC2SecurityGroup get names and ip details

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, syntax

I cannot quite get my syntax right to retrieve all the security groups and their related ip information

```
foreach ($g in Get-EC2SecurityGroup ) {
Write-host "$($g.GroupId) - $($g.Description)"
$g.IpPermissions | Select -property  IpProtocol, IpRanges, ToPort 
}
```

help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

adding out-host to this line resolved for me.

```
$g.IpPermissions | Select -property  IpProtocol, IpRanges, ToPort | out-host
```